# MVC RegularExpression annotation different result client - server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, regex, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, unobtrusive-validation

I am using unobtrusive clientside validation.

I have a ViewModel with the following data annotations

```
[DisplayName("Entrytime")]
[DataType("Time")]
[RegularExpression(@"^(?[0-1]?[0-9]|[2][0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(LocalizedResources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Time")]
public DateTime? EntryTime { get; set; }
```

The problem is that the clientside validation works fine, enabling me to input
for instance 12:20 into my field and not 25:20.

But on the server, if I ask ModelState.IsValid, I get an error on the field.

It seems that the problem is located before the colon in my regex. If I change the expression to

```
[RegularExpression(@"^.*:[0-5][0-9]$",...
```

It works fine.

But if I have

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$",...
```

It still won't accept it on the server. The changes works as expected with clientside validation.

**Is there a difference with the clientside regularexpression parsing and the serverside? It seems a bit buggy?!**

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is caused by using a datetime object in your viewmodel. The modelbinder isn't able to create a datetime object from just the time input. I usually just use a string in the viewmodel:

```
[DisplayName("Entrytime")]
[DataType("Time")]
[RegularExpression(@"^(?[0-1]?[0-9]|[2][0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(LocalizedResources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Time")]
public string EntryTime { get; set; }
```

If the modelstate is valid, parse the string to a datetime object.

Comment: Well - The modelbinder actually gives me a DateTime with the correct time. Its date part are set to today. Also, it doesn't explain why `^.*:[0-5][0-9]$` is valid but `^[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$` is not. That said - I used your workaround, and it works fine. I would like to see if some other answers come up before accepting yours.

Comment: This is a wild guess: If the modelbinder sets the value first, before validating (and it probably does), the regular expression is executed on the datetime object. This will call the tostring method on the datetime. So it will validate this string: 17-8-2011 10:00. This could explain why one regex works and the other doesn't.

Comment: After testing I would say that it is very much plausible, that you're right. Setting the expression to `^.*(?[0-1]?[0-9]|[2][0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$` worked. I am still using your first suggestion and using a string in the ViewModel instead, as I think it is a better fit. Thanks :)

Comment: also have a look at this handy dandy online regex builder http://gskinner.com/RegExr/